# Laravel Make arrays send to single <td>

Tags: php, laravel

My array looks like:

```
{"reply":{"text":"Suggestion One","postbackData":"12b2e909-d0b7-4f9c-a5e5-89522a85e8e0"}},
{"reply":{"text":"Suggestion Two","postbackData":"4b93606e-43fb-4d10-b144-f4974e9d16e7"}}
```

I have the following inside my blade with a table:

```
@foreach ($message->content->suggestions as $suggestion)
<td>{{($suggestion->reply->text)}}</td>
@endforeach
```

This makes my table return each item in new  instead of all together If possible I would like it to return each suggestion inside the single cell but distinctive to know they're separate such as inside a pod or pill style.

[image: Should all be inside the suggestions TH]

The above image shows that the data is spanning across instead of inside the one "Suggestions" column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try taking the `<td>` out of the foreach loop.

`<td>
    @foreach ($message->content->suggestions as $suggestion)
        {{($suggestion->reply->text)}}<br>
    @endforeach
</td>`

Comment: Having it outside the foreach will make it return only one result not both results in one

Comment: How does the result look after you do this?

Comment: If I just use `<td>{{($suggestion->reply->text)}}</td>` without the foreach loop I get: 

https://imgur.com/a/LN856cT

But I want to have both results inside the TD like a label

Answer (score 0):

tags needed to be outside of the content and to create the pill style I used  to fix

```
<td>
@foreach ($message->content->suggestions as $suggestion)
<span class='badge badge-success'>{{($suggestion->reply->text)}}</span>
@endforeach
</td>
```